# Bounty page layout bug

Tags: bug, design

I notice there's a bit of bug with the layout of the [bounty page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). See attached image:

[image]

Comment: What browser? What OS? Are you zoomed in/out? I can't repro on Win 10, latest Chrome.

Comment: I see it also on chrome windows 10 (http://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)

Comment: I'm on chrome latest, on ubuntu (Not zoomed in). This was taken from incognito mode logged out, with no addons.

Comment: And it can be fixed by adding `.subheader {white-space: nowrap;}`, or by removing `float: left; ` from `.subheader h1`

Comment: OK, I just updated Chrome - I see it too. Looks like a rendering bug with latest Chrome.

Comment: @Oded Is there going to be a fix for this? It seems that all the Reputation & Moderation pages have this bug.

Comment: @FrankerZ - but only on some sites - and not others. And only on specific versions of Chrome (the Canary versions don't have this). I am not convinced this is a bug on our side.