# Last Name Wrapping to Next Line in Flag History

Tags: bug, design, flag-history

In the flag history section, the last name is wrapping to the next line.

> [image]

This is causing the flag breakdown counts to be pushed to the bottom of the page, under the paging section.

> [image]

---

#### Edit:

In response to @CodyGray's comment, I am seeing this problem in Chrome on both Mac and Windows, yet it looks fine in Firefox.

#### Update:

I inspected the element, and for some reason when I comment out the `font-weight: normal` css line, my username goes back to one line. I don't know why this is affecting it.

```
.subheader h1, .subheader h2 {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    /* font-weight: normal; */
}
```

Comment: That's hilarious.

Comment: I can't repro this. What browser are you using? Your name is actually shorter than mine, so wrapping problems are not particularly common.

Comment: I think it's related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331909/bounty-page-layout-bug#comment380534_331909

Comment: @AlonEitan It does look like the same bug. If I comment out the same `font-weight: normal` for the `h1` on the bounty page, that header also goes back to 1 line.

Comment: @TotZam Maybe it's a Chrome bug (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=416858)

Comment: Weird, I don't see it in Chrome on Windows.